# xcode file open native C

Tags: objective-c, c, file, file-io, path

In an Xcode library project, I have a native .c file in which I need to open a text file from the app bundle or documents section.

In Objective-C I can do:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"txt"];
```

But this won't work in native C.

I need to use:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "rb");
```

But I'm not sure how to get the path of the 'data.txt' file.

Comment: Why? What is in the C file that you can't rework it, either to pass the file or to make it Objective-C?

Comment: If you know where the file is relative to the bin, then a relative path works just fine. If you're dealing with symlinks and the like, just [use `realpath`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html)

Comment: Simplest approach is to make it a .m file and code the Objective-C.  You can still have the C code there.  Otherwise you can obtain the path from "outside" as a parm or an out-call.

Comment: after some workaround, moved the file operations in .m file. But, was thinking, if customer has only native and needs the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stay completely in C, then you could link to Core Foundation and do something like:

```
#include "read_data.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

char * CFStringCopyUTF8String(CFStringRef aString) {
    if (aString == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    CFIndex length = CFStringGetLength(aString);
    CFIndex maxSize =
    CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding(length,
                                      kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(maxSize);
    if (CFStringGetCString(aString, buffer, maxSize,
                           kCFStringEncodingUTF8)) {
        return buffer;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int open_data_file(void)
{
    FILE *fp;

    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    if( mainBundle == NULL )
    {
        printf("unable to get main bundle\n");
        return -1;
    }
    CFURLRef dataFileURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, CFSTR("data"), CFSTR("txt"), NULL);
    if( dataFileURL == NULL )
    {
        printf("unable to locate data file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    CFStringRef path;
    if( !CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey(dataFileURL, kCFURLPathKey, &path, NULL))
    {
        printf("unable to get file path\n");
        return -1;
    }
    char *pathBuffer = CFStringCopyUTF8String(path);
    fp = fopen(pathBuffer, "rb");
    free(pathBuffer);

    return 1;
}
```

Some error-checking etc. left out for clarity.

Comment: Using the above code, it gives the following error, while running. dyld: Symbol not found: _kCFURLPathKey
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/3BE03596-268E-4257-B688-9D020049DD9B/theSampleAppn.app/theAudioAppn
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /var/mobile/Applications/3BE03596-268E-4257-B688-9D020049DD9B/theSampleAppn.app/theSampleAppn

Comment: Using the above code, it gives the following error, while running.

_italic_
dyld: Symbol not found: _kCFURLPathKey
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/3BE03596-268E-4257-B688-9D020049DD9B/theSampleAppn.app/theAudioAppn
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /var/mobile/Applications/3BE03596-268E-4257-B688-9D020049DD9B/theSampleAppn.app/theSampleAppn
 
The environment for execution is, Xcode-5 and iOS 7.0 framework.
The application contains the, 'CoreFoundation.framework'. But it still gives the error.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you link with Core Foundation?  (Target > Link Binary With Libraries)

Comment: yes, I added the Core Foundation framework and same is included the header.

Comment: I created a [sample project](https://github.com/cocoa-factory/TestCFReadFile) on github for you.